# Equivalent of Response. in Windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am trying to transfer a text data to a text file and make it downlodable. It was easy in Web Application using Response. But when transfering same thing over windows i was not able to get solution we can do it by writing data to text file but how to make that file downlodable??

This is the Code for the Web Format which i wrote

```
    private void ButtonSaveText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Build the Text file data.
        string TextFileData = string.Empty;
        TextFileData = TextFileData + "PAY SLIP FOR THE MONTH --------------" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewPaySlip.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < GridViewPaySlip.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                TextFileData += GridViewPaySlip.HeaderRow.Cells[j].Text + "\t\t\t" + GridViewPaySlip.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

        //Download the Text file.
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        string FileName = String.Format("{0}__{1}{2}", "payslip", EmployeeIdTemp, ".txt");
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        Response.Output.Write(TextFileData);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to download file from the Web into Winform app. You should probably try WebClient as described here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937797/how-to-download-a-file-from-the-web-within-a-winform-application

Comment: You can save those content to a file in specific location and prompt for save dialog ( similar to what we get in download from web app.)

Comment: @AlexBell no i am writing the file with a DataGridView Data and want to make that file downlodable on ButtonClick

Comment: @ArindamNayak i am not doing like that just dumping the values in Output Downlodable File saved file nothing else no writing no temporaray file creation

Comment: @AlokSrivastava , my point is , if you are trying to convert web to windows application, you may need to follow this path.

Comment: so there no similar method like web here?/ @ArindamNayak

Comment: @AlokSrivastava You should refer to save dialog of windows form. My guess is, you will ask for file name to save, and maintain content in memory stream and write that to file, see there is no temp file thing, that i was talking earlier.

Comment: Ok so i should copy and the write all those3 things in the text file then how to proceed further?? Any example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by "Octopoid", you're a bit confused.

Think about it. You don't "download" in a desktop application. In a web application, it's is necessary to download a file from the server to the client.

In a desktop application, there is no server and no client, so the concept of "download" does not exist.

You are probably thinking about the fact that a download in a web application may involve some dialog that allows the downloaded file to be saved in a location of the user's choice. This is what the [`SaveFileDialog` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) allows you to do. Example:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (var stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
    {
        // code to write to the stream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit of a misunderstanding here as to the differences between a forms app and a website, and the role of the web server.

In terms of creating the text file, it's really easy:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\example.txt"))
{
    file.WriteLine(TextFileData);
}
```

That's it. There are other ways, that example doesn't deal with encoding or anything, but it saves the file.

In terms of "making it downloadable", that's not really anything to do with the app. Instead you need to make sure you save the text file into a folder that your web server is serving, (and that the web server supports the file type).

`new StreamWriter("D:\\Websites\\Payslips\\payslip_" + EmployeeIdTemp + ".txt"))`

Or whatever path you might be using.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is assuming you actually meant "make the file downloadable". If you meant "allow the user to save the file", John's community wiki answer has you covered.